# What can be used instead of nested loop to speed up

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to combine two lists with a given common key.

```
l1 =  [["apple",2], ["banana", 5], ["orange",7]]
l2 = [["apple", 5,8], ["banana", 2,4], ["orange", 8,9,]]
```

Target output:

```
l3 = [["apple", 2, 5, 8], ["banana", 5, 2, 4], ["orange", 7,8,9]]
```

For a rough data, nested for loops runs really slow.  What can be used instead of nested loop?

Comment: Are both lists ordered? Same elements?

Comment: Are the fruits in the same relative order in both lists? Are the fruit names unique?

Comment: I assume the second loop is supposed to be over `l2`?

Comment: lists are not orders.  I wrote such an example to simplify. In some cases fruits maybe not in the relative order. fruit names are unique

Comment: So you could have `[8,9,"orange"]` ?

Comment: fruits must always come first

Comment: What should happen if you have a fruit in l2 and not in l1?

Comment: that's not possible for this case. each inner list has a common fruit at the other list.  But if you want you can expand the case in that direction

Answer (score 1):

If the *fruits* always come first:

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import defaultdict

l1 = [["apple", 2], ["banana", 5], ["orange", 7]]
l2 = [["apple", 5, 8], ["banana", 2, 4], ["orange", 8, 9]]

lookup = defaultdict(list)
for fruit, *numbers in chain(l1, l2):
    lookup[fruit].extend(numbers)

l3 = [[fruit, *numbers] for fruit, numbers in lookup.items()]
print(l3)
```

**Output**

```
[['apple', 2, 5, 8], ['banana', 5, 2, 4], ['orange', 7, 8, 9]]
```

This approach has expected `O(n)` complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the key is always the first element, you can convert your lists to dictionaries and then merge them.

```
>>> d1 = {l[0]:l[1:] for l in l1}
>>> d2 = {l[0]:l[1:] for l in l2}
>>> res = [[k, *d1.get(k, []), *d2.get(k, [])] for k in d1.keys() | d2.keys()]
>>> res
[['apple', 2, 5, 8], ['banana', 5, 2, 4], ['orange', 7, 8, 9]]
```

Or in case each element in `l1` is guaranteed to have a corresponding element in `l2`

```
>>> res = [[k, *d1[k], *d2[k]] for k in d1]
```

Comment: `d1 = dict(l1)` should suffice.

Comment: True, but `dict(l1)` will fail if the lists contained in `l1` do not have exactly 2 elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary for O(1) amortized lookup times:

```py
l1 =  [["apple",2], ["banana", 5], ["orange",7]]
l2 = [["apple", 5,8], ["banana", 2,4], ["orange", 8,9,]]

d1 = dict((k, v) for [k, *v] in l1)
d2 = dict((k, v) for [k, *v] in l2)

l3 = []

# set(d1) | set(d2) is a union of their keys
for k in set(d1) | set(d2):
    l3.append([k, d1.get(k, []) + d2.get(k, [])])

print(l3)
```